# If I want to run a heroku app where there is one entry per day, how many dynos do I need?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron-task

I am running a Heroku app, where there is a cronjob and it is entered once a day at a specific time to run a job, how many dynos will I need, and will the free plan be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) for this.